# Key of entity that is weak and in isa relationship at the same time

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I don't know how to create table that should represent entity that is the at the same time in ISA-relationship and also a weak entity. Ie. I have entities `Contestant`, `Judges`, `Participants` and `Club` with its attributes,`Contestant` and `Judges` are in ISA relationship with `Participants`,and `Contestant` depends of `Club` and it's weak entity (besides ISA). How should I create table `Contestant` in SQL developer? (what are the keys of that table) Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Do you need `Participants` (is it mandatory)? I would avoid this table if possible.

Comment: I planned to use it but i could avoid it..is the solution too complicated?

Comment: I would say - it is not a "relational way".

Comment: what do you mean?i would use any solution:)

Answer (score 0):

I would propose the following:

- table `person` with personal information (name, email, phone number, etc.)
- table `contest` with information about contests
- table `role` with roles for persons: "contestant", "judge", etc.
- table `participation`, which contain person ID, contest ID and role ID for current person.

Without any other details of your problem it is hard to say what else should be added to this schema.

Comment: i thought that i could write some code in few lines in create table contestant..thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of class/subclass or, if you prefer, type/subtype.  Many ISA relationships fall into this category.  Contestants and Judges are subclasses of Participants.  It's conceivable that a given person might be a contestant in one contest but a judge in a different contest.

How much complexity you want to live with depends on the data you want to manage, and what you intend to do with it.  You don't provide enough detail to answer that question in your case.  Simpler is generally better, except when it's not.

There are some properties of Participants, like Phone number, that will be common to both judges and participants.  It will be slightly easier to manage phone numbers if they are stored in a Participant table, rather than separately stored in the Contestant and Judge tables.  But it will be more complicated to manage the third table.

If you should choose to explore relational modeling of ISA relationships in more depth, here are three tags that will help you:

[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance) [class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance) [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

These three tags group together some questions and answers that are somewhat related to the question you asked.   Also, there is an info tab under each tag that gives a general description.

It is not necessary for you to learn all of this material if you are just getting started with databases.  At some point, it will likely become relevant to you.